# Access WebDriver Endpoints

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I started a Selenium server this way: `java -jar /usr/lib/selenium/server/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -port 4444`.

Within a browser (http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/static/resource/hub.html) I see the console of the running Selenium server and with the Create Session button I can start a Chrome session for instance.

Now I would like to understand the WebDriver endpoints (https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#endpoints). I simply tried a GET with a Browser or Postman to http://localhost:4444/status, but got the response "Whoops! The URL specified routes to this help page".

What did I wrong? What kind of request I have to send to get a sensemaking JSON answer?

Answer (score 0):

quite simple, use this url: http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/status. I simply missed the "wd/hub" part within the url.